# Transforming two dimensional into one dimensional binary summation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Consider two sets of real numbers $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ and $(u_i)_{i=1}^n$.

I want to find a sequence of real numbers $(t_i)_{i=1}^M$ such that
$$
\sum_{s\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nu_iv_js_is_j\right) = \sum_{\mu\in \mathcal{M}}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^Mt_i\mu_i\right)
$$
where $\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ contains binary sequences of length $n$, and $\mu$ also should be **binary** sequence of some length $M$. The set $\mathcal{M}$ and the parameters $M,(t_i)_{i=1}^M$ are to be determined so that the above equality holds true.

*EDIT*: Due to Keeran Brabazon answer I would like to emphasis that $t_i$ must be independent on the summation variable $s_i$ (or $\mu_i$).

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to simply re-arrange the order of summation and rename some variables? We have

$$\sum_{s\in\{0,1\}^{n}} \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}v_{j}s_{i}s_{j}\right) \\
= \sum_{s\in\{0,1\}^{n}} \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}s_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{j}s_{j}\right) \\
= \sum_{s\in\{0,1\}^{n}}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i}s_{i}\right)$$

where

$t_{i} = \displaystyle u_{i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{j}s_{j}\right)$

therefore

$\mathcal{M} = \{0,1\}^{n}$, $M=n$, $\mu = s$ and the above equality holds.

Comment: Yes, of course, but now the variables $t_i$ are actually $t_i(s)$, namely they depend on the sequence $s$ - which is not good for me.